# Methods returning incorrect values

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm getting this weird error in my class. I have this IRNode class where I have 3 Strings: op1, op2, and op3. When I print them out, before assign them to the different strings and then printing them out is giving different values. Its storing them as null.

The output the print statements is something like this:

```
OP1: 20, OP2: a, OP3: null

;STOREI
```

while it should be:

```
OP1: 20, OP2: a, OP3: null

;STOREI 20 a
```

My code:

```
public IRNode (String op, String o1, String o2, String o3) {

    opcode = op;
    op1 = o1;
    op2 = o2;
    op3 = o3;
    //IRNodeNext = null;

}

public void printIR () {
    System.out.format("OP1: %s, OP2: %s, OP3: %s\n",op1, op2,op3);
    String o1 = this.op1;
    String o2 = this.op2;
    String o3 = this.op3;
    System.out.print(";"+opcode);
    if (o1 != null) System.out.format(" ",o1);
    if (o2 != null) System.out.format(" ",o2);
    if (o3 != null) System.out.format(" ",o3);
    System.out.format("\n");
}
```

PS. this is for my compilers project. This is after I create the AST and the IRNode list.

*****EDIT******
Actually found out this was a stupid error. But i am now facing another weird error.

```
op1 = thisNode.returnOP1();
op2 = thisNode.returnOP2();
op3 = thisNode.returnOP3();
```

Here, I get op1, op2 and op3 like earlier. When returning, I checked, I am returning the correct values.
For example,
For STOREI 20 a
I am returning op1 = 20 and op2 = a

but when I am receiving it just after those 3 lines of code, I am getting wrong values. I am getting op1 = 20, op2 = $s, op3 = a

Why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "before assign them to the different strings and then printing them out is giving different values. Its storing them as null."? The only issue I can see here is that you have `" "` where `"%s"` should probably be. Perhaps?

Comment: That edit should be a new question, since the original question was answered. Honestly, considering what your first issue was, I wouldn't be surprised if this issue is another similar error. I will refrain from calling it what you did, just to be polite about it. What is the code for the `returnOP` methods? It doesn't look like `returnOP2()` or `returnOP3()` are returning what you are expecting them to return.

Comment: Hey u were right. It was a similar error, because of print statements, I was getting the wrong values. In my returnOP functions I am just returning the respective OP String.

Comment: Glad to hear that was the right path to walk down. If you would be so kind as to mark my answer as accepted, it would be appreciated. It is generally frowned on here to have an answer provide the solution, and leave it unaccepted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only issue I see in this example is this:

```
if (o1 != null) System.out.format(" ",o1);
```

Each of those lines should have `%s` in the empty string:

```
if (o1 != null) System.out.format(" %s",o1);
if (o2 != null) System.out.format(" %s",o2);
if (o3 != null) System.out.format(" %s",o3);
```

Without it, you aren't going to get anything printed out.

Output:

```
OP1: 20, OP2: a, OP3: null
;STOREI 20 a
```

You might also want to consider this:

```
System.out.format("%n");
```

Rather than using `\n`, use `%n` for newlines in your formatted strings. It's platform agnostic.

> *****EDIT****** Actually found out this was a stupid error. But i am now facing another weird error.
>
> op1 = thisNode.returnOP1(); op2 = thisNode.returnOP2(); op3 =
>   thisNode.returnOP3(); Here, I get op1, op2 and op3 like earlier. When
>   returning, I checked, I am returning the correct values. For example,
>   For STOREI 20 a I am returning op1 = 20 and op2 = a
>
> but when I am receiving it just after those 3 lines of code, I am
>   getting wrong values. I am getting op1 = 20, op2 = $s, op3 = a
>
> Why is this happening?

Without the code for your `returnOP` methods, it is hard to say, but based on the previous issue, I am willing to bet that the problem is similar.

Given this:

```
public String returnOP1() { return op1; }
public String returnOP2() { return op2; }
public String returnOP3() { return op3; }
```

And this:

```
    System.out.println(irNode.returnOP1());
    System.out.println(irNode.returnOP2());
    System.out.println(irNode.returnOP3());
```

I get this:

```
20
a
null
```

That tells me that, for you, `returnOP2()` is written to return `$s` instead of `op2` or `op2` is being set to `$s`, and `returnOP3()` is written to return `op2`.

But without the code, there is no way to be certain.